# Create an object of a java class whose constructor is annotated with @Autowired

Tags: java, spring

There is a class whose constructor is annotated with @Autowired. I want to create an object of this class without actually passing the constructor parameters and using the default parameters. Can someone tell me how can i create an object of this class?

Comment: Found an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons of using Spring framework is you don't create objects and manage them manually spring does it for you.If you can give some more details example code or something it will help to understand your situation better.

Comment: I should have mentioned properly. I want to use the instance which spring has created. But i am not sure about how to get hold of that object.

Comment: `ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/beans.xml");`.Then you can access the bean as `YourClass yourClass = (YourClass ) context.getBean("yourClass");`

Answer (score 0):

Spring is a dependency injection framework (it does hosts of other stuff as well). So the whole point is not to "create" your own instances and re-use the instances that Spring has created for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want create object of class whose constructor is marked as @Autowired then still you can create object of that class using normal new java operator.
You can create an object of that class by just marking your field with @Autowired.Spring handles object creation for you.